# Restrict SQL Server access for users having contributor access to subscription in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-subscription

We have added the Contributor role to my azure subscription. And all the user in my directory having the Contributor role. So all the user are able to access the databases/sql servers created in my subscription.

So the problem here is, we have production sql databases exist in same subscription. We wanted to restrict the access for the specific databases. How can we do restrict access to the sql server/database?(Consider all the users are having contributor role and contributor role is assigned to subscription)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible, unless the resources were created using Azure Blueprints, in which case, you can use a Deny Assignment to restrict access.

You will either need to assign the RBAC roles directly to the resource groups or the individual resources, rather than at the subscription level.  Or, if possible, you should consider moving your production resources to another subscription.